# Why in order to prove that the minimal of a toset is unique, the minimal element is not taken for a subset of $S$ but rather than for the set $S~?$

Tags: order-theory

I was seeing the proof of *Minimal Element in a Totally Ordered Set is unique and smallest* from [$\mathsf{Pr}\infty\mathsf{fWiki}$](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Minimal_Element_in_Toset_is_Unique_and_Smallest); this is how the proof begins:

> Let $(S,\preceq)$ be a totally ordered set.
>
> Let $m$ be a minimal element of $(S,\preceq)\,.$
>
> [...]
>
> ### Proof:
>
> By definition of minimal element: $$\forall y\in S: y\preceq m\implies m= y$$ ....

This really bothered me; for the definition of minimal element, also given in [$\mathsf{Pr}\infty\mathsf{fWiki}$](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Minimal/Ordered_Set) goes as:

> Let $(S,\preceq)$ be an ordered set.
>
> Let $T\subseteq S$ be a subset of $S\,.$
>
> ### Definition 1:
>
> An element $x\in T$ is a minimal element of $T$ iff: $$\forall y \in T: y\preceq x\implies y= x\,.$$ ....

Notice that the minimal element is defined for the **subset** of $S$ and not for $S\,.$

So, how did they write in the proof in the former excerpt above that $\forall y\in S: y\preceq m\implies m= y\,?$ The minimal element $m$ must be defined for a subset of $S$ and not for the whole set $S\,.$

Why did then, they do so in the proof above? Why didn't they take a subset and took all the $y$ belonging to the whole set $S\,?$

It seems they are  not in the agreement with the very definition of minimal element they gave.

Could anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Take $T=S$. What's the lack of agreement?

Comment: Ah! Okay @GitGud.

Comment: Are you sure it is okay? Is there anything you might be missing?

Comment: I've not completed reading the proof. But let me take your advice @GitGud.